# List of dataframes: Slicing a dataframe into a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function that should return a list of dataframes. These dataframes must not contain any of the already included values.

idx is a list of indices wherecondition is met (dummy=1).
Everything around the dummy (n) is then dropped.

My output should be a list of dataframes containing values that were not dropped, but no other (between 2 dummies). The first dataframe is OK. I count the elements and use the for loop to try and collect other slices, however, the slices do not return dataframes that are within wanted limits.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data={"A":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
                          "B":[1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                      "event":[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]})

def EstimationWindow (data, n=3, dummy=1):
    '''
    data....data. Contains ALL data - reurns, and event dummies = event column
    dummy...event=1
    n.......days before/after
    '''    
    idx = data.index.get_indexer_for(data[data.event==dummy].index)
    # Drop event window
    estwin = data.drop((np.unique(np.concatenate([np.arange(max(i-n,0), min(i+n+1, len(data))) for i in idx]))))    
#    estwin = [estwin.iloc[0:i-n] for i in idx]
    output = [estwin.iloc[0:idx[0]-n]]
    for i in idx[1:]:
        out = pd.DataFrame(estwin.loc[len(output):i-n])
        output.append(out)
    return(output)
```

The function should return a list: `output = [df1, df2]`

Wanted:

```
[   A  B  event
 0  1  1      0
 1  2  3      0
 2  3  3      0,    A  B  event
 6  7  7      0]
```

Result:

```
 [   A  B  event
 0  1  1      0
 1  2  3      0
 2  3  3      0,    A  B  event
 1  2  3      0
 2  3  3      0
 6  7  7      0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `for` loops to construct your list of split `df`s. Find the dummies, use [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) to build indexes to drop and just use straightforward [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
s = df.event.eq(1)
dummies = s[s].index

ind_to_drop = (dummies + 1).union(dummies).union(dummies - 1)
c = df.event.cumsum().drop(ind_to_drop)
```

Then

```
for _, g in df.drop(ind_to_drop).groupby(c):
    print(g)
```

Yields

```
   A  B  event
0  1  1      0
1  2  3      0
2  3  3      0

   A  B  event
6  7  7      0
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!